# C File Handling / Structure Problem

Tags: c

How does one read in a txt file containing names and marks of students and inputting them
into an array of structures.

```
maximum allowable records are 7:
e.g. James 45
Mary 70
Rob 100
```

Answer (score 1):

First, define the structure. The structure describes what a *record* is; what data it contains. Here you have a student's name and his or her mark.

Second you need to prepare the array to write the objects of the structure into. You already know from the problem description that no more than 7 students are allowed, so you can define the length of the array to that number.

Next, open the text file.

Lastly write a loop that takes as input from the file a string for the student's name and an integer (or a floating-point point number if you so choose) for their mark. In the loop create a structure for each record and insert the structure into the array.

And of course, don't forget to close the file when you're done.

That's all there is to it. If you have any syntax or logic questions then ask in the comments, and we'll gladly help.

Answer (score 0):

Read the man page for fopen: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

This should give you somewhere to start.

Also, the man page for fread and fgets could be helpful. There are many ways to read from a file and the path you choose will depend on numerous things, such as the structure of the file and the amount of security you want in your application.

Answer (score -1):

found this code that is similar enough that should be able to help you get done what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Sample data lines
5 0 Wednesday Sunny
6 2 Thursday Wet
*/

int main() {
/* Define a daydata structure */
        typedef struct {
                int n_adults; int n_kids;
                char day[10]; char weather[10];
                } daydata ;
        daydata record[30];
        FILE * filehandle;
        char lyne[121];

        char *item;
        int reccount = 0;
        int k;

        /* Here comes the actions! */
        /* open file */

        filehandle = fopen("newstuff.txt","r");

        /* Read file line by line */

        while (fgets(lyne,120,filehandle)) {
                printf("%s",lyne);

                item = strtok(lyne," ");
                record[reccount].n_adults = atoi(item);

                item = strtok(NULL," ");
                record[reccount].n_kids = atoi(item);

                item = strtok(NULL," ");
                strcpy(record[reccount].day,item);

                item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
                strcpy(record[reccount].weather,item);

                printf("%s\n",record[reccount].day);
                reccount++;
                }

        /* Close file */

        fclose(filehandle);

        /* Loop through and report on data */

        printf("Weather Record\n");
        for (k=0; k<reccount; k++) {
                printf("It is %s\n",record[k].weather);
                }

        }
```

http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=c209/lunches.c

Give a holler with code you tried if you have problems changing it to fit your needs.